# Render custom form on mail clients via Private Content for Wordpress

Tags: css, email, wordpress

So I'm using the Private Content - Mail Actions add on on Wordpress.
It allows you to send custom forms with your own css.
The thing is the render is a bit random regarding one thing (see the picture).
Some of my `<td>` doesn't display their borders. It's never the same td's it's random on every send. I'm not sure if this problem comes from my code, the plugin or the mails clients.
If any of you ever had this kind of problem I would appreciate some advices.

[image]

Comment: Does it only happen with empty <td>s? Yes, I see most of the others look empty too, but do they contain <br> or &nbsp; or anything?

Comment: Here is a sample, and it happens also with filled tds:<br/>
          '<tr>
         <td style="border: 1px solid #4497cd; padding: 10px;">[pcud-user-data f="nb-ex-01"]</td>
         <td style="border: 1px solid #4497cd; padding: 10px;"></td>
         <td style="border: 1px solid #4497cd; padding: 10px;"></td>
      </tr>'
<br/>
And yes i've just seen that the plugin fills the empty tds with &nbsp;

Comment: Sorry for the bad display i'm not yet familiar with the syntax

Comment: Well, then it probably won't help to add `style="empty-cells:show"` to the start tag of the table. Not sure what else to say.

Comment: Thanks for trying ;)